# react native show content in 2 columns

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So basically i need my GridView to look like this:
[image]

In code:

```
  <Grid style={styles.mt}>
    {this.state.listOfDiscover.map((item, i) => (
      <Row key={i}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.row}
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate("BlankPage", {
              name: item.title,
            })}>

            <View style={styles.rowItem}>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.textCreatedAt}>{item.created_at}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textBody}>{item.body}</Text>
              </View>
              <Image style={styles.newsImage} source={item.local_path} />
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Row>
    ))}
  </Grid>
```

Have been playing around with this, haven't been able to make it happen. It either shows in 1 row(the whole 8 articles ).

Comment: Please show us your styles

Comment: Isn't there a basic way to do this? 2 column row view.